# I want to replace a lot of files with differing names with the same file without changing the name, how can I do that?

Tags: file, replace, directory, rename

I have a bunch of .txd and .dff files that have different names, let's say, like, img1 img30 greenimg3, etc. all in the same folder. I can compile a list of these names that I want to replace (but not all the files in the folder will be replaced), but how can I replace my list of files with just one file without altering the name of the file? So it remains img1, img30, greenimg3, etcetera but with the replaced file. I hope this makes sense. I would be grateful if someone could write something that I could use, as I don't know how to code myself.

Comment: We need more info. What's the operating system you want to do this on? How do you want to do this (Windows - batch or Powershell script, Linux - bash, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understand corretly, but you could do this in python:

```py
import os

folder_path = "./folder"

with open("source.file", "rb") as source_file:
    source_file_content = source_file.read()
    for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        with open(os.path.join(folder_path, file), "wb") as destination_file:
            destination_file.write(source_file_content)
```

where "./folder" is the path to your folder containing all files you want to overwrite and "source.file" is the path to your file you want to overwrite with.

this script reads and writes the files as binary

Comment: Hey,

I only want to replace specifically named files inside the folder, not them all, so I would need to target them specifically whilst also keeping their filenames intact after the file was replaced.